# Inserting Image to SQLite in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

Here's the code for a 'selection' button, where it passes the NSData to the global variable to be used later.

```
 @IBAction func btnCCTV1(_ sender: Any) {
// Put Your Image URL
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string : "http://cctv-sg.com/images/sr/01.jpg")!
// It Will turn Into Data
let imageData : NSData = NSData.init(contentsOf: url as URL)!
// Data Will Encode into Base64
let str64 = imageData.base64EncodedData(options: .lineLength64Characters)
// Now Base64 will Decode Here
let data: NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: str64 , options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
// turn  Decoded String into Data
let dataImage = UIImage(data: data as Data)
// pass the data image to image View.:)
viewImage.image = dataImage

print("====64====")
print (str64)
print(imageData)

GlobalVar.data64 = imageData as NSData
GlobalVar.imageByte=dataImage
```

}

**Inserting the images to the SQLite**

```
@IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: Any) {

 let imageDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

print("==image====")
 // print(GlobalVar.imageByte)

if (imageDB?.open())! {

    let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO ImagesDB (images, photo) VALUES ('\(images)',  '\(GlobalVar.data64)')"

    let result = contactDB?.executeUpdate(insertSQL,
                                          withArgumentsIn: nil)

    if !result! {
        lblResult.text = "Failed to add images"
        print("Error: \(imageDB?.lastErrorMessage())")
    } else {
        lblResult.text = "Images Added"

    }
} else {
    print("Error: \(imageDB?.lastErrorMessage())")
}

}
```

How do I make the images just insert to `SQLiteDB` only? I am complete newbie in Swift 3, so having trouble to insert the images into the `SQLite`. Any suggestion or help is appreciated. If there are any similar swift 3 code which are able to insert images into SQLite without using FMDatabase is fine too.

Comment: any possible solution for this type of codes? needed to use SQLiteDB to store images.

Comment: Is it correct to put try database.executeUpdate("create table images(x image, y image, z image)", values: nil) ??